# Git - recover a commit

Tags: git, github

For a project, I git (and github) on a lot of pc. On one, I first checkout to get old code and I commit and push to github with respectively `git commit -a -m "Message"` and `git push --force`. I see that it work but now on an other pc when i want to get the last commit, I can't get the modifications. I try to use `git log` but the commit isn't there and I try to see it with `git reflog` but it doesn't work. How can I get it back ?

Comment: `git pull`?....

Comment: When I make git pull I don’t get the commit that I do after checkout...

Comment: are you working on the same branch on both pcs?

Comment: Yes i only use the master branch

Answer (score 0, accepted):

RUN
`git fetch`
`git checkout branch-name`

Comment: How can I know the branch-name ?

Comment: I push to master

Comment: it all about the issue of branch, i think ur not in right branch, check git all branches in ur repository in github site.

Comment: I only work with the master branch. When I check on github, there is only the master one.

Comment: if your change code display in github website then clone it again.

Comment: The code doesn't display on github website and i only use origin

Comment: Use this command replace ur origin URL `git push git@github.com:git/git.git master`

Comment: But I don't have access to the other pc where I make my modifications because it's a temporary session...

Comment: you have access of that git repo?

Comment: I have access to the repo on GitHub

Comment: On an other pc and i don’t have access anymore to this pc

Comment: Okey but you don’t know how can I fix my issue?

Answer (score 1):

Run `git fetch` and after `git pull`.
Hope it works.

Comment: Yes 
When i make git log i get
`060c5a5 il y a 4 heures Guillaume Prieur (HEAD -> master, origin/master, origin/HEAD) Ajout du drapeau de compilation C99.
b52fa7e il y a 2 jours fdep98  petite correction avec (MF) plus printf
caaf440 il y a 7 jours MrGuim  Erreur de segmentation inconnue.
2b5fc5a il y a 7 jours MrGuim  Ajout d'un buffer sous forme de liste chainée.
f22812d il y a 8 jours MrGuim  Ajout des tests et modification du Makefile en conséquence.`

On the other pc, I checkout to f22812d.

Comment: Run git status, please.

Comment: Say that i'm one master branch and say tjhat it's up to date with origin/master

Comment: Are you sure you did the git push? try again

Comment: I did it.. The problem is that i don't have again any access to the pc where I make my modifications.

Comment: And you can see the changes in the repository?

Comment: No but on the other pc, when I first `git push` and it fail then i `git push --force` and it succeed but now when i go to the repo and doesn't see any changes.

Comment: If you don't see the changes in the repository, maybe the push didn't work.

Comment: I'm sure that it work then where no conflict or hint

Comment: if the push appear in the log, but you can't see the changes in the repository, you should contact github support.

Comment: But It doesn’t appear in the log because I checkout to an old commit then I commit ... so when i pull I get the normal branché